# Converting an SQL Query to Pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have the following SQL left join query to be converted to Pandas join.

```
select df1.pc, df1.si, df1.cat,
        df2.cid As mid, df2.sd as md, df2.cid As bi, df2.sd as bd, sum(df1.sal) as Sal
        from df1
        left join df3
        on df1.cat = df3.cd 
        left join df2
        on df2.chd = df3.mid
        and df1.id = df2.id 
        left join df3
        on df1.cat = df3.cd 
        left join df2
        on df2.chd = df3.bid
        and df1.id = df2.id 
            group by df1.pc, df1.si, df1.cat, df2.cid, df2.sd, df2.cid, df2.sd ;
```

I tried the following code in pandas

```
final = pd.merge(
        pd.merge(
        pd.merge(df1, df3,how='left', left_on=['cat'], right_on=['cid']),
                    df2,how='left', left_on=['chd','id'], right_on=['mid','id']),
                        df3,how='left', left_on=['cat'], right_on=['cid']),
                            df2,how='left', left_on=['cid','id'], right_on=['bid','id'])
```

but some where I am getting wrong. Is this equivalent one? or any suggestions
please suggest...struck here

Answer (score 2):

When you are using the merge in pandas, if you did not specify the suffix for the columns with the same names in advance, it will add _x for the left columns and _y for the right ones.

```
import pandas as pd

dict = {'Name':['Martha', 'Tim', 'Rob', 'Georgia'],
        'Maths':[87, 91, 97, 95],
        'Science':[83, 99, 84, 76]
       }
  
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(dict)

df1.merge(df2,how = 'left',left_on=['Maths'], right_on=['Science']).merge(df3,how = 'left',left_on=['Maths_x','Name_x'], right_on=['Science','Name'])
```

And I saw the latter 2 merges are the same as the first 2s. It seems to be duplicative to me.

The screenshot of the result[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3GBK.png)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Able to do merge the dfs in the same way that you suggested.